# Mac App Package Identity Not Installed

Tags: xcode, app-store, osx-lion

I have a Mac app I'm trying to submit to the App Store.  I'm getting the error shown in the attached screenshot when I try to submit the app.  I created the certificate request from this exact Mac and archived the app on this Mac using the 3rd Party Mac App certificate.  All of that went fine.  But when I go to submit the app, I can't get past selecting the Code Signing Identity because it says that the package identity is not installed on this Mac.  I'm not sure how this is possible because I generated all of the certificates from this Mac and verified that they are all installed and valid.  I have submitted this Mac app previously without issue.  Has anyone else seen this?  I'm using XCode 4.3.2.

[image: Code Signing Identity Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had the same error earlier this week. The issue was in the creation of the distribution provisioning profile. Even though the "Installer" and "App Store" options in the Certificate portal are checkboxes, ensure that only one of the two are checked and generate the profiles you need. Having on the the "App Store" option checked rather than both and regenerating the profile resolved the issue for us.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm still beating my head on this one.  I even contacted Apple support and they aren't helping at all.  I will try this tomorrow and let you know if it works.

Comment: Yep that was the problem alright.  It's a bit confusing that they automatically select both but then it doesn't work...Thanks a ton!

Comment: Turns out I did have one other problem in addition to your solution - the expired certificate was still installed but was hidden from view in Keychain Access.  I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559942/mas-code-signing-identity-private-key