# MAS: Code Signing Identity Private Key

Tags: xcode, code-signing

I've removed all development and installer certificates from the development portal, created a new CSR and generated new Application and Installer certificates.

Now I'm about to distribute the App to the MAS and am constantly presented with this error:

```
"Name" is a valid identity. However, the private key for the associated package
identity "Name" is not installed on this Mac.

Developer Profiles from a different Mac can be imported.
```

This puzzles me, since the private key is on the System, how else could I've generated the certificates without them?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Double check you have removed all old certs, there is a menu item in the KeyChain app to show all expired certs. I threw away all expired certs and things started working.

Comment: Like I said, make sure you select "Show Expired Certs" under the View menu and toss all expired certs, once I got rid of some old one I could validate and submit to MAS. By creating a new user account you have effectively done the same thing.

Comment: +1 The hidden expired certificates have been biting me for days.  Xcode was seeing a code signing identity that I couldn't find in the keychain.  Turns out it was a hidden expired certificate.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been stuck on this for so long!

Comment: Deleting the expired certificates using Keychain Access, and then restarting Xcode did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working:

- Created a new user account on my Mac
- Cloned the repo there
- Removed all Provisioning Profiles and Certificates from the Dev Portal
- Let Xcode generate all the Certificates for you
- Upload works!

Comment: Use @tgunr's answer instead!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Mac Installer Distribution certificate.

The easiest way to have everything fixed and loose all the troubles just go to Xcode->Window->Organizer->Devices and then on the lower right corner press on Refresh and log in with your account... xcode will generate and download all the certificates and provisioning profiles needed.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions and deleted all expired certificates from the keychain and refreshed the profiles list within the organizer. How ever the error only vanished after I restarted Xcode.