# Error : The associated package identity has expired

Tags: xcode, cocoa, app-store, certificate, mac-app-store

I'm trying to validate an archive, before submitting it to the app store, but I keep getting the following error :

> "MY NAME" is a valid identity.  However, the associated package
>   identity "MY NAME" has expired.

There is an option to "Refresh Code Signing Identity", but nothing seems to happen.

What could be going wrong? Any ideas?

---

**Hint** : It's not my first time uploading an archive to the app store; I've already done that like 100 times. The thing is I'm using a different development machine and think that probably this is the one to blame. But I'm still confused...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue. Deleting the expired developer certificates via "Keychain Access" did the trick for me.

Comment: Note: If it helps anyone, I had to quit xcode, delete the ~/Library/Developer directory and restart xcode.

Comment: It worked for my by just restarting xcode. I was not required to remove the ~/Library/Developer directory

Comment: @MathewWaters I don't recommend deleting the Developer folder. It holds a lot more than just cache, like all Xcode themes, snippets, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

From Keychain Access, View, Show Expired Certificates and delete all of them.

[MAS: Code Signing Identity Private Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559942/mas-code-signing-identity-private-key)

Francesco Germinara

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error message, and it turns out that I needed to download and install both the Mac App certificate as well as the Mac Installer certificate, but I had only downloaded the Mac App one.