# "Profile" is a valid identity. However, you do not have the associated package identity. Developer profile from a different mac can be imported

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing

I am trying to submit my mac app to mac app store. Bust I'm unable to code sign the build properly.

I have create a distribution certificate in Develop Certificate utility and also I have created a production profile.

I have imported the certificate in my keychain properly with the private key. Also The provision profile is imported successfully in Organizer -> Window.

But When I Archive the project, and validate the iPA to mac app store, I'm getting the error:
**** "Profile" is a valid identity. However, the private key for the associated package identity "Profile" is not installed on this Mac

Some more details about project:
I'm using an external framework and open source project in my project named XMLRPC.
I have set "Skip Install" property of the project to YES.
This is not code sign.

Can you please let me know what is going wrong?
[image]

Comment: You can try this solution.....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723351/cant-validate-and-submit-an-app-to-the-mac-app-store

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing the installer certificate. You need both the distribution certificate to sign your app and the installer certificate to sign the package installer on submitting to the Mac App Store. Xcode finds the key automatically based on the name of code signing identity, the name is the same but with "Installer" append.

To fix the issue log into the [Certificate section](https://developer.apple.com/account/mac/certificate/certificateList.action?type=distribution) of Apple developer. Request a new certificate via the plus button and choose the Mac App Store installer type. Follow the steps to submit a CSR request and then simply download the certificate and drag it over to your keychain.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same warning even though I had the right profiles and code signing identities.

> “Profile” is a valid identity. However, you do not have the associated package identity.

I refreshed my code signing identities in Xcode and relaunched Xcode. The warning disappeared afterwards.