# Submission issue to Mac App Store

Tags: mac-app-store

Coming from iOS world, first time submission to Mac App Store and have been struggling for hours... please help! I have read through a few answers here and still seems to have issues.

I come to the step which it says... "(name) is a valid identity. however you do not have the associated package identity" and cannot continue. Since I come fresh, I have done:

- make sure that all expired certificates are removed
- applied for various certificates: now I have the following types: "Developer ID Application", "Developer ID Installer", "Mac App Distribution", "Mac Development"
- registered my Mac
- created development and distribution profiles and see them in Xcode organizer with status "Valid Profile"
- attached the profiles in Project/Target code signing identity

I can test the apps fine on my Mac, but cannot submit the app... what else have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out here first:
[Can't validate and submit an App to the Mac App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723351/cant-validate-and-submit-an-app-to-the-mac-app-store)

Not sure if that'll help. This may seem crude, but did you try restarting your Mac after deleting the expired certificates and submitting again? I wouldn't put it past the age old "cache" problem. It sounds like the same kind of issue that crops up when an expired identity package is in play.

Comment: I will check that out. To answer your question: yes, I did restart Xcode, and later computer, and the issue remains.

Comment: It works! The place I missed is the Mac Installer Distribution certificate. Thanks!